# Would you be interested in any questions from Augur—Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, migration

We're going to be [shutting down Augur](https://augur.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/this-site-will-be-closing-on-july-30-2019) next month and I noticed that this site has an [augur](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/augur) tag. There aren't a huge number of [questions on that site](https://augur.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes) and they will be available in an archive once the site has closed. But if there are any questions this community would be willing to host, I can migrate them shortly after the Augur site is closed. That way the content could be made available for discovery via a search engine and could be edited if needed.

Which Augur questions, if any, would be welcome on this site?